# error while dismissing view controller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

I created an iPhone app and it was running ok. So, I implemented the code for iPad and the problem began. Problem: when a view is presented, it doesn't dismiss and the app stops. The code to present the view is:

```
- (IBAction)goToSetView
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SetViewControllerIPhone"];
    [self setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

The code to dismiss the view is:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == self.view) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

And the error is:

```
NewApp(2072,0x22e11a8) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=402657280) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Other information: before the simulator shows the error message, it shows that the used memory is more than 1,5GB.
I already tried to reset the simulator but it still doesn't work. 
P.S.: Do you believe I need to reinstall xcode? Thanks.

Comment: are you using a storyboard for iPad as well?

Comment: Yes, I am using storyboard for iPad.